# Filter non zero value in a cell and copy values in seperate columns / sheet for a large data

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy only values which are not zero values in a separate sheet / column.  This needs to be done for large data.

I have tried the below vba-excel code, but getting stuck at for loop.  Note the range in the below code is given, but in a large set of data it is unknown, so it needs to find all the rows until end.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim reportsheet As Worksheet
    Dim datasheet As Worksheet
    'LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Set datasheet = Sheet1
    Set reportsheet = Sheet2

    datasheet.Select
    'finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


    'With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To Lastrow
        If Cells(i, 2).Value <> 0 Then
        'Rows(i).Delete
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 12)).Copy
        reportsheet.Select
        Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Next i
End Sub
```

Sample Data -

[image: Sample data]

Expected all the values at one column without zero value or #NA or blank cells.  I need to plot a graph with this data.  Any suggestions is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Use [`Range.Autofilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter) perhaps instead of looping.

Comment: You mention that in your posted code `the range is given` but it's not.  It dynamically finds the last row of data.

Comment: However, the posted code does have several issues.  For example, you really want to [avoid Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba), and also you copy the range but never actually paste it.

Comment: Additionally, there are fewer non-zero values in the provided sample data column B, so if your end goal is to line up the values so that there are no 0's, your second column won't have enough values to match the first column.  Basically, it seems like there's not enough information here to give you a good answer.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs,  I am new to coding, so their might be few issues with the code.  Yes, both columns are not dependent, so will run the code sepearately for each column.  If you have any best way to do both at a time then it will be great.  I need to run this for large data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. considering the columns have just numbers.

```
Sub FilterZeros()
Dim i As Long, lr As Long, lc As Long
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet

Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

'Last column
lc = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Loops between column in Sheet1 to filter valus <>0
For i = 1 To lc
   sh1.Activate
   Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=i, Criteria1:="<>0"
   n = Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
   Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(n, i)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

  'find the last column and adds the copied data in Sheet2
  sh2.Activate
  lc2 = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
  Cells(2, lc2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
  sh1.Activate
  Range("A1").AutoFilter
Next


End Sub
```

Use below the revised code without the loop to select any particular column to filter and copy the values.

```
Sub FilterZeros()
Dim i As Long, lr As Long, lc As Long
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet

Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

'First Column to be filtered
   sh1.Activate
   i = "Enter your column no. 1 here"
   Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=i, Criteria1:="<>0"
   n = Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
   Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(n, i)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

  sh2.Activate
  Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'Second Column to be filtered
  sh1.Activate
  Range("A1").AutoFilter
  i = "Enter your column no. 2 here"
  Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=i, Criteria1:="<>0"
  n = Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
   Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(n, i)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

  sh2.Activate
  Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

  sh1.Activate
  Range("A1").AutoFilter

  sh2.Activate
  Range("A2").Select

End Sub
```

Thanks,
Hafeez

Comment: Thanks @Iam_hafeez  it did worked, but only when I have seprated the columns in a new sheet from other columns.  I think you have assumed only 2 columns exists as per my question.  Sorry about that.  Can you tell me what I need to change to select data from a two specified columns only from the entire data set?  Thanks. Rupesh

Comment: Previously i wrote the code to loops through entire columns, however as per your requirement if you need to select data only from 2 specified columns. I will change the code. in this case there is no need to use the for.. next loops.

Comment: Thanks Hafeez for your time and for the code, it really solved my problem to some extent. :)